# About range of marginal probability distribution when range in the joint distribution is dependent

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

Let $X,Y$ be random variables. The joint probability distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is given by
$$f(x,y)=g(x)h(x+y); ~~-x<y<1-x, ~~0<x<1,$$
where $g$ and $h$ are given probability density functions on $[0,1]$. It is easy to check that $h$ is a valid $($joint$)$ probability density function. My problem arises when I try to find the marginal distribution of $Y$. I have
$$f^{*}(y)=\int_0^1 g(x)h(x+y)dx$$

> My question is, what will be the range of $y?$ In general, if the range of $y$ depends upon $x$ in the joint density, what will be its range when we integrate the joint density upon $x?$

My guess is : $\bigcup_{x=0}^1 (-x, 1-x)=(-1,1)$. Is it correct$?$ What is the mathematical justification$?$ Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "guess" is correct and your reasoning shown is a good mathematical justification for it.  The point is that when describing the marginal distribution of $Y$ you need to include all values that $Y$ can possibly be, for any possible value of $X$.

Comment: Thank you very much sir.